# calling static member of class pass a parameter and get return value

Tags: c++

I have a class like below with static function

```
class Car: public Vehicle
{

  public:
     static int b;
     Car(int x)
     {

         cout<<"This is Car"<<x<<endl;
      }
     static char* x1(int x)
      {
        b=x;
        return (char*)"done";
      }
}
```

I like to call the `x1` static function and pass value and get the return value. How to do it?

Comment: `char* ret = Car::x1(42);`?

Comment: `static char* int x1(int x)` what exactly are you trying to return here? Did you instead mean `static char* x1(int x)`?

Comment: @CoryKramer sorry static char* x1(int x) is correct

Comment: @CoryKramer I am getting error at this line `b=x;` any solution to how to initialize static member variables in static function?

Comment: @MikeCAT see my last comment

Comment: Then you should show what error you get....